# Recommended 64-bit OS for ETH 2.0 node on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: testnets, raspberry-pi, eth-2.0

I would like to participate in one of the current ETH 2.0 testnet with my Raspberry Pi 4B (ARM64 processor, 4GB RAM) and 500 GB USB 3.1 SSD.
Performance-wise, this is possible and I run an [ETH 1.0 full node](https://github.com/diglos/pi-gen) on it myself.

All ETH 2.0 clients I tried (even Nimbus) don't work in the 32-bit userland that comes with `Raspbian Buster`, the native OS for the Raspberry Pi.
It is unclear, when a new Raspbian version with 64-bit support will be released.

My question is, if anybody is doing this already and which OS you would recommend.

Besides the obvious choice of Ubuntu Server 20.04, which is currently in beta and supports Raspberry Pi 4, I also thought about [balenaOS](https://www.balena.io/os/). 
balenaOS is  64-bit and allows for running containers on large variety of different single board computers. Did anyone try this? Heterogenity of devices and ease of use would be a big plus - releying on their cloud service a big minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/download/arm/raspberry-pi-4/arm8-raspberry-pi-4-kde-plasma/) to run a Lighthouse node on a Pi 4 with 4GB RAM.

I went with Manjaro at the time because I'm familiar with Arch and the install process seemed quite straight forward. I used [this guide](https://raspberrytips.com/install-manjaro-raspberry-pi/) for reference.

Seeing as a Pi4 is already a fairly constrained device, for mainnet I would recommend a device *without* a desktop environment (KDE, etc). For testnet purposes and stress-testing (my use-case), having a desktop environment is fine for now.