# How to run slasher slashing detectors in Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: beacon-chain, slashings, slashing-detectors, beacon-nodes

"A validator client will likely store tens or hundreds of MB of historical votes to prevent slashings." ([Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/recommended-64-bit-os-for-eth-2-0-node-on-raspberry-pi-4b))

Do beacon nodes or validator clients automatically run **slashing detectors**?

If not, what are the instructions for running slashers (slashing detectors)?  Hardware requirements would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There’s a difference between slashing detection and slashing prevention. Detection requires storing significant amounts of data but prevention only requires quite a small amount of storage.

I’m not aware of any client that automatically runs a slashing detector - usually only slashing protection.

Comment: But there should be a way to run slashing detectors, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes you can run a slashing detector as a separate system that communicates with the beacon node via its apis (usually HTTP REST)

Comment: Upvoted but trying to get a list of the slashing systems and how to run them.

Answer (score 2):

The Prysm team implemented a slasher as a separate process.

Official documentation on how to run a slasher: https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/prysm-usage/slasher